# Cocos game Application Crash offline log

Tags: android, crash-reports, cocos2d-x-3.0

We build Android-based game Apps on the Cocos2d platform using C++ and JavaScript. App uses no internet.I can able to see the crash report when we use the android studio to debug. but how to catch the log/report when the app crashes on the mobile device when it's not connected to Computer.

Answer (score 0):

Use crash reporter, which allows your to view crash-related information on the web when a crash occurs. It's easy to integrated into your project by reference each document.

- You can use [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics) by Fabric *(recommended)*

  The most powerful, yet lightest weight crash reporting solution. You can easily integrate with your app through gradle and get crash report.

  Enable [NDK crash](https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle/ndk) reporting in your project, for more information check [this](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/crashlytics-cocos2dx-3-7-android-studio/23098/68) thread.
- [BugSense](https://mint.splunk.com/)